# spark - java heap space issue - ExecutorLostFailure - container exited with status 143

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am reading the string which is of length more than 100k bytes and splitting the columns based on width. I have close to 16K columns which I split from above string based on width.

but while writing into parquet i am using below code

```
rdd1=spark.sparkContext.textfile("file1")

{ var now=0
 { val collector= new array[String] (ColLenghth.length) 
 val recordlength=line.length
for (k<- 0 to colLength.length -1)
 { collector(k) = line.substring(now,now+colLength(k))
 now =now+colLength(k)
 }
 collector.toSeq}


StringArray=rdd1.map(SubstrSting(_,ColLengthSeq))
#here ColLengthSeq is read from another schema file which is column lengths



StringArray.toDF("StringCol").select(0 until ColCount).map(j=>$"StringCol"(j) as column_seq(j):_*).write.mode("overwrite").parquet("c"\home\")
```

here ColCount = 16000 and column_seq is seq(string) with 16K column names.

I am running this on Yarn with 16GB executor memory and 20 executors.
File size is 4GB.

I am getting the error as

```
Lost task 113.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 461, gsta32512.foo.com): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 28 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: 
Container marked as failed: 
container_e05_1472185459203_255575_01_000183 on host: gsta32512.foo.com. Exit status: 143. Diagnostics: 
Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143
Killed by external signal
```

when i checked the status on UI its showing

```
#java.lang.outofmemoryerror java heap space
#java.lang.outofmemoryerror gc overhead limit exceeded
```

Please guide on performance tuning of above mentioned code and spark submit parameter optimization

Comment: You definitely do not need 16*20 GB total memory to process a 4GB file

Comment: I tried with 4GB and 8 GB executor memory but it gets failed very early with Heap space issue hence i keep it as 12 GB or 16GB.

Comment: If I had to guess, you're collecting all information within a single executor, and it blows up... Look at the Spark UI to see which tasks and stages are performing the most work and reading the most data

Comment: no. of executors are 20 and executor memory is 12 G

Comment: Again, are there single executors doing more work than others?

Comment: Can you add DAG graph and ui images

Comment: All executors were having same storage memory 692kb /6.7GB .. but input data for executors is different.. few were handling 4 gb data whereas the dead executor was having only 400mb data....

Comment: I ran for two times and observed that both times executor 2 and 19 got failed .... And input for these two executors are less compared to other executors

Comment: Have you tried writing it out as a CSV? Just to check if writing to parquet is causing any issues, as parquet writers need to keep some data in RAM before writing compressed blocks to disk. Also have you tried trimming the strings?

Comment: trimming is not required as requirement to write data as it is.  if I write to CSV and then again I need to convert to Parquet. I can try that .... now the only problem i am facing is fixed width string is 120000 and having 20k columns which is taking lot of time (more than 48 hours)for 2 TB file. Appreciate if anyone can suggest some optimization tips here