# Spark Fixed Width File Import Large number of columns causing high Execution time

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata, hadoop-yarn

I am getting the fixed width .txt source file from which I need to extract the 20K columns. 
As lack of libraries to process fixed width files using spark, I have developed the code which extracts the fields from fixed width text files.

Code read the text file as RDD with

```
sparkContext.textFile("abc.txt")
```

then reads JSON schema and gets the column names and width of each column.

- In the function I read the fixed length string and using the start and end position we use substring function to create the `Array`.
- Map the function to RDD.
- Convert the above RDD to DF and map `colnames` and write to Parquet.

The representative code

```
rdd1=spark.sparkContext.textfile("file1")

{ var now=0
 { val collector= new array[String] (ColLenghth.length) 
 val recordlength=line.length
for (k<- 0 to colLength.length -1)
 { collector(k) = line.substring(now,now+colLength(k))
 now =now+colLength(k)
 }
 collector.toSeq}


StringArray=rdd1.map(SubstrSting(_,ColLengthSeq))
#here ColLengthSeq is read from another schema file which is column lengths



StringArray.toDF("StringCol")
  .select(0 until ColCount).map(j=>$"StringCol"(j) as column_seq(j):_*)
  .write.mode("overwrite").parquet("c"\home\")
```

This code works fine with files with less number of columns however it takes lot of time and resources with 20K columns. 
As number of columns increases , it also increase the time.

If anyone has faced such issue with large number of columns. 
I need suggestions on performance tuning , how can I tune this Job or code

Comment: It's difficult to say without your code examples. it could be related to this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40320563/spark-udf-called-more-than-once-per-record-when-df-has-too-many-columns.
Could you post you code and spark `.explain()` plan?

Comment: have a look at representative code mentioned in previous thread       https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51118204/spark-java-heap-space-issue-executorlostfailure-container-exited-with-stat

Comment: Could you provide syntactically correct and well-formatted piece of code and Spark explain plan?

Comment: Hi Dmitry could nit provide the code and plan  as it's organisation confidential .

Comment: Looks like you load the data _twice_ in memory. Did you consider using an efficient parser (like univocity) to read the raw file and build the RDD one record at a time? _(note that Spark has the option to use univocity to load CSV into DataFrames so you have something to start with in the Spark repo...)_

Comment: Thanks Samson . I am new to spark . Reading RDD twice , does it mean while I first load into RDD and again apply map function second time. Can I use cache here to avoid reading two times.  Can you please guide me in detail