# reading very wide data set performance optimization

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, bigdata

I am importing fixed width file from source which very wide dataset having fixed width string length close to 120000 and i need to extract 20K columns from that and  write to parquet.

Can anyone suggest me some performance optimization techniques which can reduce the  file reading time.  I am reading the source file as RDD. but it takes lot of time.

Can anyone suggest different ways which will reduce the time like JAVA IO stream.

Comment: Why do you use RDD instead of Dataframe?

Comment: Source file is Fixed Width file and I need to map function to RDD which splits the columns based on width in schema. Currently there is support for fixed width file from spark

Comment: Put your code to see if it can be optimized

Comment: link to code : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51118204/spark-java-heap-space-issue-executorlostfailure-container-exited-with-stat

Comment: How often do you open that file? Would converting it to Parquet or ORC, which are optimised for the projected scans, and than using those for repetitive reads be acceptable?

Comment: Haven't tried this option to convert .txt to parquet and then reading. But I have tried other options like repartitioning , caching but no significant improvement